# Compiling statement collection to an action

Tags: c#, dynamic, expression-trees

So lets say I want to return an action like so ...

```
public Action<T1, T2> BuildActionFrom(object[] stuff)
{
     BinaryExpression[] expressions = BuildExpressions(stuff);
     return (x,y) => {
          foreach(var ex in expressions) ex(x,y);
     };
}
```

... how might I go about building this as I can't find anyhting in the expression building api that seems to allow me to build that return value?

Each of my expressions are pretty simple (basic property assignments and what not), I just can't figure out how to put them together.

Comment: What is `stuff` and `BuildExpressions`? I don't understand what you're passing in or receiving from this method.

Comment: Hmm ... changed slightly ... stuff is sort of irrelevent tbh ... but the net result is that I want to take a collection of expressions and build them in to an Action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it ...

```
Expression.Block(expressions);
```

... was what i was looking for!